# Run a Thread every 15 seconds even if app is in background in Swift

Tags: swift, nstimer

My app gets data from webpage every 30 seconds (game's updated score). The problem is that my setInterval runs fine if the app is foreground and the user is looking at it.

But once the user opens anyother app and send it to the background my thread stops.

Is there a way to make it work even if app is in the background.

```
func setInterval(interval:NSTimeInterval, block:()->Void) -> NSTimer
{
    return NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: NSBlockOperation(block: block), selector: #selector(NSOperation.main), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

This is my function call setting up interval

```
handle = setInterval(TIMEOUT_SEC, block: { () -> Void in

    // do this stuff after 30 seconds
    self.sendScoreService()
})
```

Comment: Hello Matt: The app is constantly updating the hardware and displaying result there. The people who use this app, use it with hardware.  They dont like their phone blocked while they are connected with hardware. They want to use their phone, check mails, check photos, facebook etc. When they do that, app goes in the background. It is not hard scenario

Comment: Guys no reason to downvote a perfectly good question. There can be 100s of VALID reasons to run an app in the background. Cant believe some guys here have some tunnel vision. Mobile phones have replaced many devices in common household and they are also used to manage hardwares. Disappointed by downvote. Sorry

Comment: Matt: I didnt know you downvoted :) I was talking to whoever downvoted. I did search 2 hours before posting. I used several search terms. Just sometimes when you have no clue how to achieve something then you dont even use the right terms. My terms never returned any suitable results. So after 2 hours, I posted a question. I appreciate your concern but I was just unable to find answer. Jon's answer pointed me in right keyword "background services"

Comment: If the purpose is to stay connected with hardware (as an aside, this would have been a salient detail to add to the question), how are you connecting with that hardware? For example, there are `bluetooth-peripheral` and `external-accessory` background modes. See this discussed in the link that Jon shared with you.

Comment: @Rob I am using bluetooth low energy

Comment: @Rob I am sorry I didnt mention the hardware aspect in my question.

Comment: No worries. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html. I'd suggest that you accept Jon's answer to close this general "background requests" question, research the `bluetooth-peripheral` approach and post a question on that, if you have questions about handling background bluetooth notifications. Bottom line, you can't just poll a web server every 30 sec, but there are background bluetooth notification processing capabilities.

Comment: Accepted his answer. I am reading on the background services as well as bluetooth-peripheral approach. Thanks for your valued input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polling is your worst case scenario here. It's something that shouldn't be done unless there is absolutely no other way, as it's terrible for performance and especially battery life, especially if your intention is to do so every 30 seconds in the background, forever. Users will notice that your app is burning their battery and will blame your app for their device's poor performance.

The better solution here is to setup a push service your app registers with that will push new score information to your app whenever it's actually needed, rather than your app having to poll for it. This will maximize your apps efficiency and allow your users to use other apps with a minimum of impact.

If you absolutely, positively must have background operation, there are some things you can do. First, read [Apple's background services documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) and then implement a background operation according to those guidelines. But think deeply about your issue before you do this.

Comment: Jon: thanks for your reply. Anyone who is using the app will know that the app will run in background even. Infact they will start this service by pressing a button. They want it to run even in background so that while scores are being downloaded in background they have their phone available to them

Comment: So YES i am 110% positive that I need background options and app users will be happy with it. Infact they want it.